# Javascript function not recognized when clicking on link

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the 'simplified' JavaScript code below there is a problem with the function `message_category_ref()`, which creates a link for some elements. When clicking on the created link the console shows the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError - showTopics is not defined.

When I include an `alert()` function in the return statement instead of showTopics (as shown below), `alert()` is called. Not sure why `showTopics()` is not recognised and how to solve this?

**Simplified code:**

```
userapp = function(){

  var showTopics = function(catid){

  }//showTopics()

  var showMessageCategories = function(){
   showList4('Berichten','general-com','html','MessageCategoryTable',
             ['Categories','Subjects','Messages','Last message']);
   addRow('MessageCategoryTable',['Privat message']);
   for(var i=0,i_max=message_categories.length;i<i_max;i++){
       addRow('MessageCategoryTable',[message_category_ref(message_categories[i]['catname'],message_categories[i]['catid'])]);
       addRow('MessageCategoryTable',[message_categories[i]['catdescription']]);

   }//for
   //message_categories[0]

  }//showMessageCategories

  var message_category_ref = function(catname,catid){
    //this one does not work
    return '<a id="myLink'+catid+'" href="#" onclick="showTopics(\'' + catid + '\');">'+catname+'</a>';

    //this one works
    //return '<a id="myLink'+catid+'" href="#" onclick="alert(\'' + catid + '\');">'+catname+'</a>';
   }//var message_category_ref

  return{showMessageCategories:showMessageCategories}

}(); //userapp


$(document).ready(function(){

   userapp.showMessageCategories();

}); //$(document).ready
```

Comment: `onclick` can only access global functions. Your function name is local to the `userapp` function.

Comment: Have you tried `userapp.showTopics` in your `onclick` event?

Comment: @Barmar - make an answer out of your comment.  This is the problem.

Comment: @Pavlo That would work, but he has to expose the method first.

Comment: Guessing here, but I wonder if userapp().showMessageCategories() would work the way you want it

Comment: @stakolee `userapp` is an object not a function. It would be `userapp.showMessageCategories();`. See @Barmar's answer for clarification...

Comment: @stakolee I thought that as well, until you see the `()` at the end of the anonymous function definition that initializes `userapp`, which invokes said anonymous function immediately, so the returned object is assigned to `userapp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function name is local to the anonymous function you use to initialize `userapp`, so it can't be accessed from an `onclick` attribute -- these expressions are evaluated in the global scope.

Change the `return` line to:

```
return{showMessageCategories:showMessageCategories,
       showTopics: showTopics};
```

Then you can do:

```
onclick="userapp.showTopic(...
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not global. It is located within a closure. You need to add it to your return object to allow it to be accessed outside `userapp`:

```
return {
    showMessageCategories: showMessageCategories,
    showTopics: showTopics   // Add this to your return Object
};
```

Also change your `onclick` to reference it like so:

```
onclick="userapp.showTopics(\'' ... )"
```